# Learning Markov Decision Processes from Puterman's text with limited mathematical background

Tags: probability, reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I am studying Markov Decision Processes (MDPs) using Puterman's classic text, but am finding it challenging due to my limited background in measure theory and Borel subsets. Additionally, the lack of solutions for the end-of-chapter problems makes it difficult for me to check my own work. I would appreciate any advice on strategies for effectively learning the material in this book, such as supplementary resources to fill in gaps in my mathematical knowledge, ways to test my understanding of key concepts, or suggestions for alternative MDP texts that may be more accessible for someone with my background. My ultimate goal is to develop a deep understanding of MDPs and their theories as well as mathematical modeling using MDPs to develop novel MDPs for research.

Does anyone have suggestions to understand MDPs at the level covered in Puterman's classic text with a limited mathematical background?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.